# AWS CLI SQS for localstack - cannot set queue attribute

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-sqs

I am trying to change one of queue parameters in my localstack but it does not work. I am getting the following errors:

```
    aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url http://localhost:4566/000000000000/BatchReadyToProcessRequest --attribute VisibilityTimeout=3600 

An error occurred (InvalidAddress) when calling the SetQueueAttributes operation: The address https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ is not valid for this endpoint.
```

Any idea why it is trying to talk to amazonaws.com when I use localstack?

The queue name is correct because it is returned by command

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs list-queues
```

I am following these docs: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sqs/set-queue-attributes.html

-Jacek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might already be too late but did you try adding  `--endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566` to the `set-queue-attributes` call?